# Qt 5.5 - Windows API not Working as usual

Tags: c++, windows, qt, c++11, winapi

I am using **Qt 5.5** on **Windows 10** and I want to open a `QWidget` in **Foreground** and want to **focus** the `LineEdit`, like RUN (WIN + R) on Windows. The Problem is the Application is running in the background and I have only an keylogger to register a shortcut (LCTRL + LWIN + T) to toggle the window (show + focus / hidden).

If the shortcut is pressed, I execute following Code:

```
   if(this->isHidden()){

      this->show();

      //Windows API Methods:
      SetActiveWindow((HWND) this->winId());
      SetForegroundWindow((HWND) this->winId());
      SetFocus((HWND) this->winId());

      this->_edit->setFocus();

      qDebug() << "[OUT][DONT WORKING] Window shoud be shown and focused";
    }else{
      this->hide();
      qDebug() << "[OUT][WORKING] Window shoud be hidden";
    }
```

If I now press **LCTRL + LWIN + T**, it opens the Window in the background and that's not what I want. Can someone explain why this does not work? What can I do that the window opens in the foreground and the text box is **focused**? And I don't want to set the flag `StayAlwaysOnTop`, because then the text field is still not focused.

I hope you can help me.
Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

It was not possible, becouse to set the ForegroundWindow i have to get the current Input, i did following:

Construcor:

```
HWND wId = (HWND) winId();
DWORD pId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(wId, NULL);
AllowSetForegroundWindow(pId);
```

onShortcutPressed:

```
this->show();
HWND wId = (HWND) winId();
DWORD pId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(wId, NULL);
DWORD fpId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), NULL);

//Attach Thread to get the Input - i am now allowed to set the Foreground window!
AttachThreadInput(fpId, pId, true);
SetActiveWindow(wId);
SetForegroundWindow(wId);
SetFocus(wId);
AttachThreadInput(fpId, pId, false);
```

Its working now!